# AccessDenied Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to get an access token to upload large files as [described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online).

I am using client credentials grant flow to get access token [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). I got an access token using that flow.

I tried to use that access token with this URI:

```
/v1.0/users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

but it gives me an error that "AccessDenied Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token"

I have granted admin permission for the app. I have tried this flow in both postman and in coding but both give the same error.

Comment: What scopes did you request?

Comment: Application: SitesReadwrite.All Delegated: FileReadwrite.All. permissions have been granted by admin

Comment: `Sites.ReadWrite.All` should be all your neee. Please add the Access Token you're getting back to your question.

Comment: okay.i have been informed that tenant admin has not yet granted the permission to app.they are have some signing issues with error code  while granting permission to app "AADSTS165000: Invalid Request: The request do not match the user context."
what does this error code indicate?

Answer (score 2):

Well as Marc pointed out Sites.ReadWrite.All was the only permission i needed, it was just that permission had not been accepted by admin.so the roles were not visible in my access token.Now i am able to call graph api using that access token.